# How to make resources and java folder test based in gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, integration-testing

I have created a custom module in sourceSets called as **integration** for keeping all my integration test cases. The configuration is working fine but the only project is the in the **integration** folder the **resources** folder is not `Test Resources Root` and **java** folder is not `Test Sources Root`. I want the **intergration** folder java and resources to looks exactly like the **test** module like as shown below.

[image]

In the above picture if you observe the **java** folder looks green under test folder but under integration folder **java** folder looks blue in color.

What I except: I want the **java** and **resources** folder in **integration** folder looks exactly like that of **test** folder. ie. If you observe in the screenshot my **main** and **integration** folders looks exactly the same. But instead I want the **integration** folder to make it look exactly like the **test** folder

My gradle `sourceSets` look like this

```
sourceSets {
    integration {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ I can change it by right clicking onto the **integration>java** folder **Make Directory as> Test Sources Root**

and

**integration>resources** folder **Make Directory as> Test Resources Root**

[image]

but I would like to know how to achieve this via build.gradle

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: I have some difficulties to understand your question, to understand what you want, what is working, and what is not working. Could you please try to make your question clearer?

Comment: What am I missing? In your screenshot, your java and resources folder in integration look exactly like the test folder, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MarioVarchmin If you observe in the screenshot my **main** and **integration** folders looks exactly the same. But instead I want the **integration** folder to make it look exactly like the **test** folder

Answer (score 6):

**Add Integration Test Module**

→ https://ryanharrison.co.uk/2018/07/25/kotlin-add-integration-test-module.html

To add a testIntegration module, you can make some edits to your build.gradle file to define a new source set (IntelliJ module):

```
sourceSets {
    testIntegration {
        java.srcDir 'src/testIntegration/java'
        kotlin.srcDir 'src/testIntegration/kotlin'
        resources.srcDir 'src/testIntegration/resources'
        compileClasspath += main.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output
    }
}
```

You also have to define a new Task to run the integration tests, pointing it to the classes and classpath of the testIntegration source set instead of the inherited defaults from test:

```
configurations {
    testIntegrationImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    testIntegrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task testIntegration(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.testIntegration.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.testIntegration.runtimeClasspath
}
```

If you run Gradle with the option to ‘Create directories for empty content roots automatically’, you should see a new module get created. You might notice one issue though, the new module is not marked as a test module within IntelliJ. You could do this manually, but it would get reset every time Gradle runs. To override this, you can apply the idea plugin and add the source directories of the new source set:

```
idea {
    module {
        testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.testIntegration.java.srcDirs
        testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.testIntegration.kotlin.srcDirs
        testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.testIntegration.resources.srcDirs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to have this red-green-arrow symbol on the resources folder icon? In **Eclipse**, you could simply rename your `integration` sourceset to `integrationTest`, and the Eclipse gradle plugin would interpret the name accordingly.

In **IntelliJ** you have to apply the gradle `idea` plugin and set the `testSrcDirs` like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
  integration
}
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
  module {
    testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.integration.java.srcDirs
    testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.integration.resources.srcDirs
  }
}
```

Look here: [IntelliJ should be aware that a custom sourceSet contains Test sources](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151925?_ga=2.250317185.642391774.1617351921-1976567438.1617351921#comment=27-2355076)

Comment: I applied this but still it looks the same

Comment: why do we need to rename the folder from `integration` sourceset to `integrationTest`

Comment: I understand now that your question is related to IntelliJ, and rewrote my answer accordingly.

Comment: if we specifically mention idea....how abt in eclipse and other IDE

Comment: In Eclipse, all you have to do is rename the sourceSet from integration to integrationTest. I am using Eclipse. I don't know how other IDEs handle this.

Comment: If I have three folder can I do like this inside idea module `def testPackages = ['unit', 'acceptance', 'integration']
  testPackages.each {
   testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets[it].java.srcDirs
        testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets[it].resources.srcDirs
  }` or do you suggest something cleaner way

Comment: That looks nice. I don't have anything better to offer.